# what is weighted position vector?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I know what is position vector but don't know anything about weighted? A article I have encounter says:

*A weighted position vector is a vector which points from the origin to an object and has magnitude **m**, where **m** is the mass of the object. I.e. (**m⋅r**).where **r** is a position vector pointing from the origin to the object.*

Is it meant for only objects with mass? or something else.
Please explain as I am beginner in vector.

Link for that article: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/linear-momentum/center-of-mass/a/what-is-center-of-mass

Comment: Given a particle has position vector $\mathbf{r}$ and mass $m$, I suppose it's weighted position vector should be $m\mathbf{r}$. However, this has magnitude $m\Vert\mathbf{r}\Vert$, not $m$. Perhaps they meant $m\hat{\mathbf{r}}$. But I've never heard the term "weighted position vector before". Perhaps you're talking about center-of-mass?

Comment: @Ghost Perhaps the way to get a definitive mathSE answer is to share the **context** of the definition.  Is this definition from a book or a class?  Assuming so, what definitions, theorems, or problems come shortly before or shortly after this definition?  Giving insight as to how the definition is used will facilitate *reverse engineering* what the definition is intended to signify.

Comment: Yes I was reading about center of mass where that term came from.Please check out our link.

Comment: @Ghost the linked article strikes me as consistent with the explanation hinted by the last sentence in K.defaoite's comment.  Suppose you have a uniformly dense sphere, precisely centered at the origin.  Then its **weighted position vector** (aka **center of mass**) is the origin.  If (for example) you move the sphere 1 unit along the x-axis, then its new center of mass is (x=1, y=0, z=0).  Alternatively, if the sphere is (instead) centered at the origin, but is top heavy (i.e. for y>0, the sphere is made of gold, for y<0, it's made of rubber), then the center of mass will be x=0,z=0, y>0.

Comment: That's clear partially.I want to what they meant m.r?  Why I am multiply with mass?I doesn't make any sense in coordinate system according to me.

Comment: Why do you think that multiplication with mass doesn't make any sense? Is it because you get another unit (dimension) $ML$ (e.g. $\mathrm{kg\ m}$) instead of $L$ ($\mathrm{m}$)?

Comment: Actually I can't understand the notion of it.